# open question on intersecting rectangles - reference request

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

In the now-inactive (and very nice) "Tricki" website that describes various proof techniques, there is an article (written I think by Timothy Gowers) that describes the following Ramsey-type problem:

Given n axis-aligned rectangles in the plane, what is the largest m such that there are always either m disjoint rectangles, or m rectangles intersecting in one point. The given proof shows that $c \cdot \sqrt{n} / \log(n) \leq m \leq \sqrt{n}$.

http://www.tricki.org/article/Extra_logarithmic_factors

It is mentioned that closing this gap is an open question. Where can this problem (and related background) be found in a research paper or book? Is it still open in this form or was there some progress on it?

Comment: I agree with bof, the inequalities should probably be $c\sqrt{n}/{\log n} \le m \le \sqrt n$.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I updated the question.

Answer (score 5):

There has been some research on a related problem, finding a smallest transversal for sets of rectangles with a given maximum number of disjoint rectangles. Small transversal implies many rectangles intersecting in one point, but not vice versa. The problem seems to be still open.

Here are some references:

[Károlyi, On point covers of parallel rectangles, 1991](http://www.akademiai.com/content/7551825h16148x0l/)

[Fon-Der-Flaass and Kostochka, Covering boxes by points, 1993](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9390587J#)

[Ahlswede and Karapetyan, Intersection Graphs of Rectangles and Segments, 2006](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F11889342_68)

[Akopyan, On Point Coverings of Boxes in $\mathbb{R}^d$, 2008](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.3405)

Comment: For a newer mention of the problem, see problem 1 on page 18 here: http://www.renyi.hu/~emlektab/emlektabla3problems.pdf

Answer (score 3):

This is not a direct hit, I realize, but as no one else has offered a reference...

> Mandal, Ritankar, et al. "Greedy is good: An experimental study on minimum clique cover and maximum independent set problems for randomly generated rectangles." arXiv preprint arXiv:1212.0640 (2012).

- [arXiv abs](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.0640)
- [PDF download](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.0640.pdf)

The Abstract, followed by Fig.2:

---

[image: GreedyIsGood]

---

[image: Fig.2]

---

Comment: (While I was posting, Jan Kyncl posted several relevant references.)

Comment: This just released, 2Oct2014: "A fractional Helly theorem for boxes," ([arXiv abstract link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.0467)).